# Matplotlib mathtext does not understand basic delimiters with right/left

Tags: latex, matplotlib

When using `\left` and `\right` in matplotlib with mathtext parsing, it doesn't recognize useful delimiters.  In particular, brace and square bracket are errors:

```
ylabel(r'$\left\{ \frac{a}{b} \right\}$')
ylabel(r'$\left[ \frac{a}{b} \right]$')
```

In both cases I get something like

```
ParseFatalException: Expected a delimiter
$\left\{ \frac{a}{b} \right\}$ (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
```

On the other hand `\left{` (incorrectly leaving off the backslash) does actually work.  I can't find any way to make the square bracket work, though.

I couldn't find any bug reports on this, but maybe I'm looking in the wrong place.  Any ideas what's going on?

(`matplotlib.__version__ = '1.1.0'`)

Comment: `ylabel(r'$\left\{ \frac{a}{b} \right\}$')` gives me the error you report, but `ylabel(r'$\left[ \frac{a}{b} \right]$')` does not, though I had to increase the font size to confirm that the result was as expected. Do you normally escape these characters in LaTeX?

Comment: In LaTeX, you have to escape the braces if you want them to show up (but not the square brackets, which I didn't escape).  In fact, if I turn on TeX processing with `matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True`, then these examples both work.  But I don't want to do that.

Comment: My guess is that this is an example of how matplotlib's parser is *not* exactly like Tex. According to the tutorial, all you need is `\left(` or `\right)` and no escape character, and that must extend to `{}` and `[]`... http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/mathtext.html#fractions-binomials-and-stacked-numbers

Comment: Actually, on that page, in the [delimiters section](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/mathtext.html#symbols), `\{`, `\}`, `[`, and `]` are explicitly listed as delimiters.  Somehow they just don't get recognized by `\left` and `\right`.  I guess it's just a bug.  I'll try to find where to report it.

Comment: I think you report it here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues

Comment: It was just a bug.  Over on github, mdboom suggested a fix [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/715) which still needed just a little work to get it right (see my comment below his patch).  Hopefully, it'll make it into matplotlib release 1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be able to put this question to bed, this was [just a bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/715), and will be fixed in a future release.